# WeakEventManager for Action<>

Tags: c#, weak-references, weakeventmanager

I know that WeakEventManager is applied for delegate:

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

However, I would like to use WeakEventManager for Action as below:

```
public class SourceEvent
{
    public event Action<int, int> MyEvent;
}

public class Listener
{
    private SourceEvent source;
    // Add listener
    source.MyEvent += listener_handler;
    // I want to replace operator "+" by AddHandler of WeakEventManger 
}
```

Do you have any suggestion for this case.
Thank in advance!

Comment: Events should have the signature `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<T> where T : EventArgs`. Please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern).

Comment: @dymanoid , thank you for reply, however i maintain the source code and i don't want to change Action to EventHandler